# Append part of byte to another byte

Tags: c#, binary

I want to take the first 4 bits of one byte and all bits of another bit and append them to eachother.
This is the result I need to achieve:

[image]
This is what I have now:

```
private void ParseLocation(int UpperLogicalLocation, int UnderLogicalLocation)
{
    int LogicalLocation = UpperLogicalLocation & 0x0F;   // Take bit 0-3
    LogicalLocation += UnderLogicalLocation;
}
```

But this is not giving the right results.

```
int UpperLogicalLocation_Offset = 0x51;
int UnderLogicalLocation = 0x23;

int LogicalLocation = UpperLogicalLocation & 0x0F;   // Take bit 0-3
LogicalLocation += UnderLogicalLocation;

Console.Write(LogicalLocation);
```

This should give  0x51(0101**0001**) + 0x23 (00100011),
So the result I want to achieve is 0001 + 00100011 = 000100100011 (0x123)

Comment: It almost seems like you think the `+` will perform the equivalent of string concatenation. What makes you think `0x51 + 0x23 = 000100100011`?

Comment: I know this is the smartest comment you have ever read, but your function `ParseLocation` does not return anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to left-shift the `UpperLogicalLocation` bits by 8 before combining the bits:

```
int UpperLogicalLocation = 0x51;
int UnderLogicalLocation = 0x23;

int LogicalLocation = (UpperLogicalLocation & 0x0F) << 8;   // Take bit 0-3 and shift
LogicalLocation |= UnderLogicalLocation;

Console.WriteLine(LogicalLocation.ToString("x"));
```

Note that I also changed `+=` to `|=` to better express what is happening.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're storing the upper bits into bits 0-3 of `LogicalLocation` instead of bits 8-11.  You need to shift the bits into the right place.  The following change should fix the problem:

```
int LogicalLocation = (UpperLogicalLocation & 0x0F) << 8;
```

Also note that the bits are more idiomatically combined using the logical-or operator.  So your second line becomes:

```
LogicalLocation |= UnderLogicalLocation;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
int LogicalLocation = (UpperLogicalLocation & 0x0F) << 8;   // Take bit 0-3
LogicalLocation |= (UnderLogicalLocation & 0xFF);
```

...but be careful about endianness! Your documentation says `UpperLogicalLocation` should be stored in `Byte 3`, the next 8 bits in `Byte 4`. Do achieve this, the resulting `int LogicalLocation` needs to be split into these two bytes correctly.